# Confusion in definition of peripheral spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

If $A$ is a closed operator, then the peripheral spectrum of $A$ is defined to be all those points in the spectrum with modulus equal to the spectral radius.

However, I came across a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.09020.pdf) which defines it as
$$\sigma_\text{per}(A)=\sigma(A)\cap (s(A) + i \mathbb R)$$ where $s(A)$ denotes the spectral bound of $A,$ i.e., $s(A)=\sup\{\text{Re } \lambda:\lambda \in \sigma(A)\}.$

My question is:  Are the two definitions equivalent? If not, then what is the reason to define it in this way?

**Edit:** This question has now been answered [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291811/confusion-in-definition-of-peripheral-spectrum)

Comment: Do you mean $s(A)$ is the boundary of the spectrum? Any bound would seem to be real, which would not intersect with the imaginary numbers, except $0$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts $s(A)=\sup\{\text{Re } \lambda:\lambda \in \sigma(A)\}.$